# In Linux, how to save log output to a file after it has been produced?

Tags: linux, command-line, scrapy

I just ran a Scrapy spider which took about 2 hours to crawl (see screenshot below), but I forgot to use the command-line option `--logfile FILE` (cf. https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#command-line-options) to save the logged output to a file. I would still like to do this, however, to track down some of the `ERROR`s that occurred during scraping.

Is there any way to 'retroactively' do this without re-scraping for another 2 hours?

[image]

Comment: Highlight it to copy and then paste in into a text editor? But if it is longer than your terminal scroll buffer length then you are out of luck. Anyway, this is not a programming question and is thus off-topic for Stackoverflow. Probably better suited to [unix.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options, however no way to retrieve the data **after** the process is done as bash(and other shells) don't log output.
You can try copying it from shell but you will only get the last few lines since by default unix terminals have limited scrollback history. There are some ways of increasing the scrollback but it's generally not recommended, see related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/385901/how-to-see-more-lines-in-the-terminal 
Instead make sure to enable logging to file explicitly:

#### Linux output redirection:

```
# only sdout
scrapy crawl spider > output.log
# both stdout and stderr
scrapy crawl spider &> output.log
# to file and stdout
scrapy crawl spider 2>1 | tee output.log
```

#### Scrapy way:

```
scrapy crawl spider -s LOG_FILE=output.log
scrapy crawl spider --logfile output.log
```

scrapy supports `-s` flag for overriding settings and there's `LOG_FILE` setting that can be used in this case and can be set in project (e.g. `setting.py` file) to always output to log file.